# Date and Time helper for PHP (like Joda-Time in Java)

Tags: java, php, datetime, date, jodatime

I am looking for a library (open source) like [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) in the Java world. Is there any library like that?

Joda-Time is very helpful to calculate date and time. I can add days, weeks, month, year  and also can converting date and time easily.

I wish there is library like Joda-Time for PHP.

Edit: I need some functions that available in Joda-Time like daysBetween (to calculate number of days between 2 date), monthsBetween and weeksBetween ... 
Some functions about add and substract date is available from PHP itself.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you are looking for : https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Comment: No, not really. It does not support different calendar systems. I filed a bug to `brock/date-time`: https://github.com/brick/date-time/issues/17

Answer (score 0):

I know a component of the [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework): Zend_Date. It works fine for this job.

I am not sure, but you can use it without the whole Framework.

[Zend Date](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.9/en/zend.date.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Joda, but did you took a look into [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)? It does all the things (and some more) that you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) and [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) can sometimes do wonders, especially if you are working with dates >= 1970 *(ie, which can be coded as a UNIX timestamp)*.

If you are using a recent enough version of PHP, the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class (added in PHP 5.2 ; but several methods were added in PHP 5.3) might be helpful too -- other [Date and Time](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) classes could help, too.

Comment: thanks, i just knew about strtotime. :) 

strtotime is nice but there are no functions like, daysBetween, weeksBetween, monthsBetween. joda have all i need to plays with date.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library for PHP Date and time
http://nuclearscripts.com/php/scripts-and-programs/date-and-time/php-date-library.html

Quoting from there

> The PHP Date Library is collection of
>   professional native PHP functions to
>   work with dates. It does not require
>   any PHP extensions. This library
>   includes most useful functions to work
>   with dates. It includes functions to
>   validate the date, shift date by given
>   amount of days, calculate difference
>   between two dates, calculate week
>   number for given date and much more.
>   It properly handles leap years and is
>   ISO compatible. Professional
>   programmer has spent 3+ days to study
>   the subject, code the library, write
>   manual and put it all here.

I havn't tested it personally.

Answer (score -2):

There is no need for external library. PHP is more than capable of this already.

```
<?php
/** These examples work with the current time **/
echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
echo strtotime("10 September 2000"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";
echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";

/** This is a made up time **/
$lessMonth = strtotime("06/19/1986 3:00PM")
$lessMonth = strtotime("-1 month", $lessMonth);

echo $lessMonth, "\n";
echo gmdate('c', $lessMonth);

/** 86 400 seconds in a day */
$daysBetween = (strtotime("now") - $lessMonth) / 86400
?>
```

Comment: Comparing standard PHP date function with Jodatime seems to indicate that you have not spent much time with Jodatime ... ;-)

Comment: This shows exactly what you shouldn't do!  Hard coding seconds is absolutely wrong.  This doesn't take into account : leap years, daylight savings, time zones, even leap seconds!  Don't do this.